# constraint on two different columns combinations

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm a bit lost here.

I have a table with 4 columns on regular rdbms (postgres to be exact)

columns are::
a1,b1,a2,b2

I don't want the combination of a1,b1 to be identical to a2,b2

I know i can potentially use triggers in order to do it.

But the question is, 
Is there a simple way to do it using simple constraint on the table?

Or do I really have to resort to using triggers validation?
I rather of course use the option of simple table constraint :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use a check constraint:

```
alter table t
    check (a1 is distinct from a2 or b1 is distinct from b2)
```